# How to make ">" work in Batch File?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a Batch File where you can get input from the user and i want it to look like this:

```
###################
#    Batch File   #
#                 #
# Enter Value     #
# >               #
###################
```

So i am using this code:

```
echo Batch Title
echo.
echo Enter Value
set /p input= >
```

But with this code when i open the CMD file it immediately close. And in my editor the ">" is highlighted. I also tried to escape it like this /> but it didn't work what am i supposed to do. Sorry if the question is not good but i am new here and also new in Batch Programming. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: To protect spaces and special characters you can surround the SET statement with quotes.  This has been a best practice for me for many years and it never hurts to just always do it. `set /p "input=>"`. You can do this for any SET command regardless of needing the quotes or not.  Just a best practice to always use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape it using `^`. I changed your example which now looks like this:

```
echo Batch Title
echo.
echo Enter Value
set /p input= ^>
```

[This](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) is a very nice collection of all the different escape character rules for batch files.

As well this overview remarks that it is also possible to doublequote the greater-than sign. Here is the quote:

> May not always be required in doublequoted strings, but it won't hurt - [Source](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

Comment: Thanks! The collection was really helpful and my problem got fixed :D

Comment: Glad I could help. You should definitely add that collection to your bookmarks! It really comes in handy sometimes. Would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: I downloaded a copy of that collection. And Yeha sure I was going to accept it but you have to wait 10 minutes before you do that so...

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in Quotation marks (`""`) and you'll be fine:

```
echo Batch Title
echo.
echo Enter Value
set /p input= ">"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the escape character `^`

`echo ^>`